# How to add inline Javascript code properly with drupal_add_js for a Drupal Commerce checkout pane?

Tags: hooks, commerce

I have a custom checkout pane with a basic validation callback. That pane function `commerce_checkout_xyz_pane_checkout_form` adds some inline Javascript code with `drupal_add_js()`.

**The problem**, that Javascript only appears on the initial form and is not added when the form is shown again after failed validation.

I thought about moving the `drupal_add_js()` to a `$form['#after_build']` callback but I don't know if that's the right thing to do and how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're using [hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/core-architecture/info-hooks/checkout-info-hooks#checkout-pane)

Try using [$form['#attached']](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) to add your js to the checkout pane form instead. That may work better there.

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/checkout_pane.js',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this inside the validation callback function:

```
if( empty($foo) ) {
    $form_state['#rebuild'] = TRUE;
    form_set_error('foo', t('Foo error'));
}
```